# JQuery Datepicker not displaying or working

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to include a jquery datepicker on a contact form.

Unfortunately, it is not working for an unknown reason (It is working within other forms on the same site)

Could someone help clarify why it is not working? it simply acts as a text box at the moment without any popups:

Please note: The form is stored within a card, not sure if this may affect it but I have heard forms and cards do not mix well

Scripts:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js">
 </script>
 <script>
    $( function() {
          $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
              dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
          });
      } );
 </script>

 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="datepicker">Pick a date</label>
     <input type="text" date-date-format="yy-mm-dd" name="datepicker" 
     id="datepicker" class="form-control">
 </div>
```

Console returns:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function at
>   HTMLDocument. (index.php:20) at fire
>   (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232) at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith]
>   (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362) at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4.js:3582) at
>   HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.12.4.js:3617)

Comment: And you're sure that is the only element with that id in the markup?

Comment: Does the console say anything?

Comment: Didnt actually think of checking the console. It says:Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.php:20)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4.js:3582)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.12.4.js:3617)

Comment: Hi Adam, yeah that is the only element with the datepicker id

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fx6gz8kh/

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
It appears that I had what I thought was an unrelated script at the bottom of the page, and the two clashed and caused an error

Comment: Ah, that will do it! Glad you found the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'de suggest using the Google CDN, rather than jQuery's servers.
Since you are using php, you may want to add the type="text/javascript" to your script tags, to see if that makes a difference.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```